# Copy from sheet 1 to sheet 2 with condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula, copy

I have sheet 1 that has values from 1 to 100 in column A. For each value there is another corresponding value (random numbers) in column B.

In sheet 2 in column A, I have some of the values from column An in sheet 1, and some that are not present there. I want in column B in sheet 2 to copy the values from column B in sheet 1 where the values in column An in the two sheets match.

Example:

```
sheet1: A1= 5, B1=4,50
sheet2: for all cells in column A, where it equals 5, set the value in B to 4,50
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this formula in `sheet2!B1`

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!$A:$B,2,0)
```

and copy down as far as needed.

After this has calculated you can `copy pastespecial values` if you want to replace the formulas with values

Answer (score 0):

use VLookup. you can find the tutorial here http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/vlookup.php